# Azure DevOps execute container job in container agent

Tags: azure-devops

I start Azure DevOps container agent with `docker run -e VSTS_ACCOUNT='kagarlickij' -e VSTS_POOL='Self-Hosted' -e VSTS_TOKEN='a***q' -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker mcr.microsoft.com/azure-pipelines/vsts-agent:ubuntu-16.04-docker-18.06.1-ce`

my pipeline has the following lines:

```
    pool:
      name: Self-Hosted
    container: kagarlickij/packer-ansible-azure-docker-runtime:2.0.0
```

..and get: `[error]Container feature is not supported when agent is already running inside container. Please reference documentation (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=875268)`

Is it possible to Azure DevOps execute container job in container agent?

Comment: Have you tried to [bind-mount the Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#using-docker-within-a-docker-container) socket?

Comment: Yes, I do use points as you can see from line 3 above